# Removing nested arrays

Tags: javascript

I have an array that contains a lot of base attributes and multiple nested arrays. I'm trying to remove the nested arrays leaving all the base items. I don't want to filter them out by name but type.

```
{
    "ID": 123,
    "ItemName": "Item1",
    "CommentList": [
        {
            "CommentID": "ABC",
            "CommentText": "Test entry"
        }
    ],
    "ExtraList": [
        "A123B"
    ]
}
```

The desired outcome is:

```
{
    "ID": 123,
    "ItemName": "Item1",
}
```

I tried filter but couldnt get it to work, the below is the closest I've come but given the fact I can't gracefully return the property back to the caller this must be the wrong track.

```
  let test = arr.forEach(function (item) {
    for (var propertyName in item) {
      if (!Array.isArray(propertyName))
        return propertyName;    
    }
  });
```

Comment: you should check my answer, i think that would help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, `Array.prototype.forEach` does not return a new array.  Please use `Array.prototype.map` instead if you would like to return a new array.

I am only saying this because you are assigning it to test, which would return undefined.

With that out of they way this should work

```js
data.forEach(item => {
for(const key in item) {
    if(Array.isArray(item[key])) {
        delete item[key]        
    }
}
})
```

Here is the code that input and output:

Input:

```js
const data = [
{
    "ID": 123,
    "ItemName": "Item1",
    "CommentList": [
        {
            "CommentID": "ABC",
            "CommentText": "Test entry"
        }
    ],
    "ExtraList": [
        "A123B"
    ]
},
{
    "ID": 124,
    "ItemName": "Item1",
    "CommentList": [
        {
            "CommentID": "ABC",
            "CommentText": "Test entry"
        }
    ],
    "ExtraList": [
        "A123B"
    ]
}
]
```

Output:

```js
[
{ID: 123, ItemName: "Item1"},
{ID: 124, ItemName: "Item1"}
]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is correct way to delete objects properties. It will not cause memory leak! While filtering or copying array will leave original array in memory, thus causing memory leak!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const a = {
  "ID": 123,
  "ItemName": "Item1",
  "CommentList": [
    {
        "CommentID": "ABC",
        "CommentText": "Test entry"
    }
 ],
 "ExtraList": [
    "A123B"
 ]
}

const obj = {};

Object.keys(a)
.filter(key => !(a[key] instanceof Array))
.forEach(key => obj[key] = a[key]);

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

arr is an object, you can get an arrays of keys with `Object.keys(obj)` an then filter it.

```js
let obj = {
  "ID": 123,
  "ItemName": "Item1",
  "CommentList": [{
    "CommentID": "ABC",
    "CommentText": "Test entry"
  }],
  "ExtraList": [
    "A123B"
  ]
}

let test = Object.keys(obj).filter((key) => {
  return !Array.isArray(obj[key])
})

console.log(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Do this way, The easiest way to Do this

```js
const data = [
{
    "ID": 123,
    "ItemName": "Item1",
    "CommentList": [
        {
            "CommentID": "ABC",
            "CommentText": "Test entry"
        }
    ],
    "ExtraList": [
        "A123B"
    ]
},
{
    "ID": 124,
    "ItemName": "Item2",
    "CommentList": [
        {
            "CommentID": "CDE",
            "CommentText": "Test entry 2"
        }
    ],
    "ExtraList": [
        "A123BC"
    ]
}
]

let finalOutput=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data,['ID','ItemName']))
console.log(finalOutput)
```